# inserting,updating data from dataset to a table ignoring duplicate value

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

all, I am making an inventory management system and in that there in one page i am taking data from a gridview to a dataset and now i want to insert that data into a "purchase" table but i want to insert only that item (itemnumber) in purchase table which is not previously inserted by user. If that itemnumber is already inserted then it should update quantity of that itemnumber from using value from dataset otherwise it should insert whole fields from dataset. Please tell me how can i do this.

Comment: Can you post your code what you have tried?

Comment: The way it is phrased currently, this sounds like a question from a homework assignment. What are you trying to accomplish in SQL terms?

Comment: if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{string consString = @"@"Data Source=abhi\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LMCINV.MDF;Integrated Security=True"";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(consString))
{using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Update_Purchase"))
 {
                     cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                             cmd2.Connection = conn;
                             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purupdate", dt);
                             conn.Open();
                             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                             conn.Close(); }}}

Comment: Show the code for "Update_Purchase" procedure. Also, post the codes in your post not as a comment so things will not get confusing.

Comment: CREATEPROCEDURE[dbo].Update_Purchase] purupdate PurchaseType READONLY
AS BEGIN     SET NOCOUNT ON;  --UPDATE EXISTING RECORDS     UPDATE purchase SET purqt = p1.purqt+p2.purqt FROM purchase p1 INNER JOIN purupdate p2 ON p1.itemno = p2.itemno where p1.itemno in (Select itemno from purupdate) and p1.department in(Select department from purupdate) --INSERT NON-EXISTING RECORDS     INSERT INTO purchase     SELECT *  FROM purupdate
WHERE itemno NOT IN(SELECT itemno FROM purchase) and department NOT IN(SELECT department FROM purchase) END

Comment: could you please write right procedure for this coz i think im not able to write correct stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue and now it is working fine. thanks all.
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @temtable t join purchase p on t.itemno=p.itemno WHERE t.itemno=p.itemno)
BEGIN
    --update existing record
    update purchase set purqt = purchase.purqt+t.purqt from @temtable as t where t.itemno = purchase.itemno
    --UPDATE [dbo].[purchase] inner join @temtable ON [purchase].itemno = @temtable.itemno SET [purchase].purqt = [purchase].purqt+t.purqt WHERE p.itemno = t.itemno
    --UPDATE [dbo].[purchase] SET [purqt]=[purqt]+10
    --WHERE [itemno]=20150860
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --insert new record
    INSERT INTO purchase select * from @temtable
END